# Cluster Elasticsearch docker with kibana in mutiple hosts

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cloud, kibana

I want set up a cluster of elasticsearch on docker and one container of kibana in mutiple hosts, i have 3 hosts and i want configure 1 container elastic per host to make a cluster, and 1 container of kibana in this cluster. But i don't find documentation for this.

It's possible ? how make ?

I need configure in the compose or elasticsearch config ?

I tested on both (compose and elasticsearch config), this is my elasticsearch  config:

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
node.name: "es-node1"
node.master: true
node.data: true
network.host: IP es-node1
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["IP es1", "IP es2", "IP es3"]

# minimum_master_nodes need to be explicitly set when bound on a public IP
# set to 1 to allow single node clusters
# Details: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17288
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

but when i access: localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty

return:

```
    {
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 5,
  "active_shards" : 5,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 10,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 33.33333333333333
}
```

Comment: Check this article. This might help.
https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/04/29/running-a-3-node-elasticsearch-cluster-with-docker-compose-on-your-laptop-for-testing/

Comment: Also check this.
https://github.com/mcascallares/es-demo-cluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: This solutions are to cluster in 1 host, and i need for 3 hosts(VM) with container of elasticsearch to make a cluster